# How can I change / specify the Output-PDF Name and Directory?

Tags: pdftex, pdf, compiling, directory

I am a beginner in LaTeX, I use TeX Live and TeXstudio.

To create my resume, I’m using this template  https://fr.overleaf.com/articles/abdallah-meddahs-cv/zhfgzbfnzdpq

But I don’t know how to specify my *Output-PDF Name* and *Directory*.
Also I want to put the compilation files (`.aux .synctex .run .bcf ... etc``
) in separate folder.

Could someone help me please?

Comment: Don't do it. Let the files where pdflatex and other tools are expecting to find them. It will save you from time consuming and complicated debugging of wrong configurations.

Comment: @Ulrike do you have an idea about how to specify the pdf name and its directory ?

Comment: Yes, I know the options (you can find them in the documentation). But I'm very good at LaTeX and I don't use them for good reasons.

Comment: Where I can find the documentation concerning this problem please?

Comment: Gummi ad LyX work on copies in the temporal directory, so you will not have auxiliary filesin the working directory. But note that this also could produce unwanted consequences (e.g.: `\jobname` will point to the name of the temporal copy, not to the original file).